# Не работает регулярное выражение которое должно удалять вторую точку и число после него

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

имеется регулярное выражение, которое удаляет вторую точку и число после него:

```
/(.*?[.].*?)[.].*/g
```

оно работает для PCRE, для js не работает

```js
let str = "1.9.90"; 
let res = str.match(/(.*?[.].*?)[.].*/g);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Попробуйте все же использовать replace и возвращать 1 группу `$1`

Comment: так тоже не работаео

Comment: `console.log( str.replace(/(.*?[.].*?)[.].*/g, '$1') );` всё работает, вы не правильно пробовали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то сложно вы ищите вне зависимости от среды обитания.
Если у вас заведомо известный порядок — [число][точка][число][точка][число]

То и искать надо соответственно: **/\d+.\d+/g**

```
let str = "1.9.90"; 
let res = str.match(/\d+\.\d+/g);
console.log(res);
```